# Anyway to preview/delete photos on iPad without transferring them first (Canon 5D Mark III)?

Tags: tethering, ipad

I know there are a lot of solutions for wirelessly tethering or transferring files, but it's not clear if I can use any of these solutions to just preview and delete photos?

My use-case is after a day of shooting, to use a larger screen (ipad) to quickly go through and delete lots of photos. I want to be able to keep the cheapest iPad and not have to worry about storage issues.

Are there any dongles, SD accessories, or wireless devices that support this really well? If you've tried this, are they really slow previewing/deleting to the card?

** It looks like Canon 6d and the EOS wifi app allows previewing and deleting. Any solution like this for the 5D Mark III? 
http://blog.martinbelan.com/2013/02/the-new-wi-fi-feature-on-the-canon-6d/

Comment: If you don't already have an iPad, [this](http://dslrcontroller.com/) might be just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Agree with Chinmay Kanchi - while I didn't put it in my answer since you specifically asked about doing it in the Apple world, it is far FAR easier on a comparatively open device like an Android tablet that doesn't actively try to prevent you doing something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best bet might be something like this: http://www.camranger.com

Seems to allow remote access and deletion of files. Not sure of the speed or stability though, and fairly expensive.

Comment: In theory it should be as reliable as using the EOS Utility.  It would be working off the same protocols.  It's basically just a small PC functioning as a USB host to the camera that is remote controlled over Wifi and uses the same exact communication.  (It might even use the same libraries, though I can't be sure from the detail on their site.)

Answer (score 0):

If the iPad is on a version of iOS that has a jailbreak available, you can simply plug in a card reader and access the memory card directly through software like iFile.  No need to hook it to the camera (though host device support should work at that point too).  I don't have any direct experience with doing this since I use Android (ironically, due to the fact they give more more native access to hardware and make these hoops unnecessary), however I do know people who have done this in the past on iOS and a quick Google search provides details, necessary files and videos on how to do it pretty easily (exact instructions vary depending on model and iOS version).

You would then just need a viewer capable of reading CR2s assuming that you shoot RAW.  If you shoot JPEG, it would be even easier. CR2 viewers are available for iOS.  PhotoRaw is one example, but there appear to be many other options as well.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is both the easiest and most cost effective way to go about accomplishing this goal.  The requirements of the question were only to have the ability to review without using space on an older iPad that they appear to want to get for this purpose.

Comment: Could be the lack of direct experience, or maybe the strong editorial content. You've written a great many excellent answers, but this isn't one of them.

Comment: @Caleb - thanks for the guess.  I tried to tone down the editorial content a bit while still explaining why I don't have direct experience.  I do know for a fact that it works though even though I have not done it personally, I know people who have done it.  I wouldn't be surprised to not see much in the way of up votes for this answer cause I agree it isn't great, but nothing seemed openly downvote worthy about it to me that I can fix.  I just posted it because it is probably the cheapest, easiest solution.  If someone else wants to post a more detailed way to do it.  By all means, I'd +1 it.

Comment: Update - after some more digging, it appears that there isn't currently a verified jailbreak for iOS7 devices, so this is much more unlikely to be useful if the device has been updated, at least until a jailbreak is completed.